# Celery' pytest fixtures don't work as expected during http request

Tags: python, django, pytest, celery

everyone.

Probably I'm missing somethig on how to use celery' pytest fixtures during a test that involves a task execution during an http request. Celery' docs that shows the pytest integration: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.3.4/userguide/testing.html#pytest

Using 'celery_session_app' and 'celery_session_worker' fixtures I can directly call the task and use `wait()` or `get()` to wait for task execution. Sample code for this case:

```py
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase
from polls.tasks import task_send_mail


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_app')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_worker')
class SendMailTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_send_mail(self):
        task: AsyncResult = task_send_mail.delay(
            email_address='mail@mail.org.br',
            message='Hello'
        )

        # waits for task execution that just sends a simple mail using
        # from django.core.mail import send_mail
        task.get()

        # it passes because the code waited for mail send
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

However, if I call the same task inside a django view, the task is executed assynchronous and the test fails because the assert is tested before the mail is sent.

```py
# view

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from polls.tasks import task_send_mail

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['__all__']


class GroupView(ListAPIView):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # task is sent to async execution
        task = task_send_mail.delay(
            email_address='mail@mail.org.br',
            message='hello'
        )
        return Response(
            status=200,
            data={}
        )
```

And when pytest executes the test...

```py
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase
from polls.tasks import task_send_mail

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_app')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_worker')
class SendMailTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_request_url(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('groups')
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            200
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            len(mail.outbox),
            1
        )
```

It returns a failed result `AssertionError: 0 != 1` because the tasks was sent to async execution and is not complete when the assert is made.

The only way I found to solve this problem is changing celery config fixture inside the conftest.py file:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'task_always_eager': True
    }
```

Is there a way to always wait for async task execution without set 'task_always_eager'?

I expected that as I'm using `celery_session_app` and `celery_session_worker` fixtures as decorators for the TestCase class, the code would wait for every async task sent to execution to finish before keeps the code execution.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, you can run Celery in eager mode.

In this mode, tasks will be executed locally in the same process in which they're called, rather than being sent to the worker queue.
This makes it synchronous. You can set it in your test setup:

```
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
class YourTest(TestCase):
    ...
```